# How to Save Videos That Play in Browser

Tags: video

When I first installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I started to do some work on a course I'm taking. There are plenty of videos in the course modules. The first video I attempted to watch in browser downloaded the video instead of playing it when I clicked the play symbol in the middle of the screen shot. I have not installed any software to perform this task, and it did this for many of the next videos. The next time I access the course and tried to play/download the next video, it played it in browser instead of downloading it. I would much prefer to have the video downloaded, but, I can't find a way to download it now that it's playing in browser.

Comment: which browser are you using? is it happening for all browsers or just some?

Comment: Hello. Any question about 22.04 is off topic as that version does not exist yet.

Comment: Sorry, @David, that was a type. I corrected it.

Comment: @ishimwe, I am using FireFox. That's the only browser I use. But, like I mentioned, I haven't changed anything on the laptop since it first downloaded them instead of playing. It seems to have just changed out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not write what browser do you use. I assume it's Firefox.

The simplest option that works if the video has been just embedded on the page without any "tricks" is to right click on the video and select "Save Video As" from the menu that appears. But many pages block this and display their own menu when right-clicking on a video, that doesn't include the download option.

Another thing that you can use is to download the video from "Page Info" window. But to get to that function, you need first to turn on the classic menu bar in Firefox. Here's how to do it: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-menu-bar-firefox

Once you have the menu bar active, click Tools->Page Info in the menu when you are on the page with the video, and then click "Media" button in the window that appears. If you're lucky, you may find the video on the list of items. Click on it, then click "Save as" button.

This also doesn't work on some pages that purposefully hide the videos from downloading. But because you were once able to download the video, I assume the site you are using is not of that kind :).

Third option is to use developer tools in Firefox. Click Tools->Browser Tools->Web Developer Tools in the menu and the developer tools pane will appear at the bottom of your browser window. Click the Network tab and try to play video (you may need to reload the page first). Again, you may find your video on the list of items and when you right-click on it, you can either select Copy->Copy URL and then to paste that URL into another browser tab to download the video, or just click Open in New Tab which should basically give the same result.

Comment: Thank you! The "Page Info" option worked and I was able to save the video!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a video downloader GUI that you might want to use for downloading from many (but not all) web pages.

It is a small, but powerful drag'n drop [tool](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader):

A deb file can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejentiger-moratai/+archive/ubuntu/mediatools)

[image]